# Recursive move files of specific type to a specific path

Tags: bash, find, xargs, mv

In ~/my/path, I want to move all files that contain string "(J)" and have file type of ".foo" to ~/my/path/j

I'm trying:

`[me ~/my/path]$ find -type f -name "*(J)*.foo" -print0 | xargs mv -0 j/`

No luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
find ~/my/path -type f -name "*(J)*.foo" -exec mv {} ~/my/path/j \;
```

Comment: Didn't know you actually wanted the brackets around the J, just added them. You're more than welcome.

Comment: John T, This solution seems very elegant and efficient but I'm having trouble understanding what the {} really means. I understand that is the "variable" being used for the mv command, but what else can the {} do? And just for clarification, the \; is used to terminate the exec?

Comment: When using `-exec` with `\;`, the `{}` is replaced with the current file or directory found that matches your criteria. `\;` will fork a new `mv` operation for each result found. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

The `-0` needs to go right after the `xargs`.

```
find -type f -name "*(J)*.foo" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv \{\} j/
```

By the way, posting an error message or other details instead of "no luck" helps diagnose problems.

Comment: I tried this too and I got this output:
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the curly braces in. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
mv `find -name *(J)*.foo` -t /my/path
```

Comment: Although with this solution you might get the "argument list too long" error; in this case, the one proposed by Dennis worked for me.