# Selectively find and move specified files to folder

Tags: ubuntu, bash, mv

I need to place the whole set of the Google web fonts in a single folder on my Ubunu 14.04 server.  I have downloaded the current snapshot from [Github](https://github.com/google/fonts/archive/master.zip) which upon expansion gives me the structure

```
/fonts-master
|
 apache
|
 ofl
|
 ufl
```

Each of these sub folders in turn contains multiple folders - one for each font.  Each font folder contains one or more *.ttf files.  What I need to do is to grab each of these ttf files and place it in the folder /googlefonts.

I could write a PHP script that would do the job.  However, I suspect that there is a way to do the job via a few simple shell commands.  Roadblock: I know my way around BASH to do simple stuff like move & copy folders and files but that is about it.  I'd be grateful if someone here could tell me how/if this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from: [Recursive move files of specific type to a specific path](https://superuser.com/questions/103151/recursive-move-files-of-specific-type-to-a-specific-path), and modified for usage with your question:

Try

```
find /path/to/fonts-master -type f -name "*.ttf" -exec mv {} /path/to/put/fonts \;
```